# Parsing Geopackage (gpkg) file in JavaScript into array

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geopackage

I am a beginner with GIS. I have the following code that is successfully creating and displaying a map:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px"></div>
<script> 
    var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 1);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibnVtaW51czEiLCJhIjoiY2treTN3YzduMDcgf34ubXPjMWNpemdicyJ9.McJEAeE0Jbj617Ozz4l5Zg', {
        attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Now, I am using the following geopackage https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gpkg/gadm36_IND_gpkg.zip to draw state lines on my map (for just one of the layers):

```
var stater = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
 geoPackageUrl: 'assets/geospatial/gadm_india.gpkg',
 layerName: 'gadm36_IND_1',

 style: {color: 'green'}
}).addTo(map);
```

This, too, is working. Now, I know that the polygons within are stored in a binary format; I also know that each polygon has a 'name' column (the innards of the gpkg can be seen here: https://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/)).

How can I convert the gpkg file into an array that I can easily traverse through?

My primary aim is this: for each state, I have a number ranging from 0 to 10 for each state; I want to create a chloropleth map (https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). What I am lacking is the ability to transform the gpkg file into the same type of array that they are using (https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You say you want to...

> How can I convert the gpkg file into an array that I can easily traverse through?

...but I do not think you want to *convert the data into a structure you can traverse through*, I think you just want to *traverse through the data*.

Now, the [geopackage-js documentation](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js/tree/master/leaflet) states:

> GeoPackageFeatureLayer extends L.GeoJSON and accepts all options for L.GeoJSON in addition to the following:

...which means you can use things like [`L.GeoJSON`'s `onEachFeature`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-oneachfeature) and [`L.GeoJSON`'s `filter`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-filter), so you can traverse, iterate and filter through features in a `GeoPackageFeatureLayer` the same way that you would do in a plain `L.GeoJSON`.

I particular, you should be able to specify a callback function as the `style` option, just in the same way that is done in the [Leaflet choropleth example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/), e.g.:

```
var stater = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
 geoPackageUrl: 'assets/geospatial/gadm_india.gpkg',
 layerName: 'gadm36_IND_1',

 style: function (feature) {
   if (feature.something) {
     /* etc */
   }
 }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. Could you link me to some documentation regarding that feature object?

Comment: You mean the [GeoJSON spec](https://geojson.org/) section 3.2? [OGC simple features access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features)? Since it's not exactly GeoJSON, the GeoPackageFeatureLayer code might decorate `feature`s as it sees fit, and you might be better off `console.log()`ing them to see their structure.